# Lost. Work sheet cross reference

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am studying for a practical Excel test for a job promotion, and this topic has me lost. here goes.

1. I created a work book with an alphabetical of employees (test one).
2. I sorted and got all the data to move. Column a is employee Id numbers, column b is ID numbers, column C is telephone numbers, (test 2).

Now here is where I'm lost.

On another work sheet in the same work book, I have to be able to type in an ID number in workbook 2, column a, and have the data from Worksheet 1 appear in columns B (employee name which is column b and phone number which is column C)

I have seen various formulas, of which none are working.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not asking for a script, asking for help.  Thank you. I will remove myself.

Comment: What do the formulas you mention look like? Ar they using the vlookup function?

Comment: +Sheet(emID)!(B)

Answer (score 0):

As datatoo hinted, use the =Vlookup() function.  This is a very handy formula to know.

```
Use Column A as the Lookup Value
Use the List on Worksheet 1 (Col a through C) as the Table Array
Use Column C on Worksheet 1 as the Column Index number
and do not use a Range Lookup (False as the last parameter).
```

Read the help on the function to get the official description of the formula.

Make sure you have calculations set to Automatic.  Otherwise, the returned value will not change when you enter a new value in A.